# Posting A Message From a Website To Twitter

Tags: twitter

Is it possible to post a message from a website to twitter account? For Example, If a user post a comment in my website, that comment should also be posted to my twitter account. Is there any API or any PHP based scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://emmense.com/php-twitter/; it uses curl to communicate with twitter.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Twitter API ; you can check it out here https://dev.twitter.com/